# What does the sh:cannot set terminal process group (-1) inappropriate ioctl for device error mean?

Tags: shell

I am trying to run a little init script instead of sysvinit, which drops me in a shell. My code for the init script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin

mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -t devtmpfs none /dev

exec sh
```

But when it drops me in the shell this error appears:

```
sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
```

The command `tty` returns `/dev/console`. I am dropped in as root and the set of commands that I tried are working correctly.

Comment: I seems that prompting a shell from this init script won't give access to a device like `tty0`, but will only let it run on `/dev/console`. However prompting the shell with `/sbin/getty -l sh -n 38400 tty0` will result in having access and running the shell on `/dev/tty0`.

Comment: What shell and OS is this? You've got `/usr/sbin` twice in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 6):

That error message likely means shell is probably calling `tcsetpgrp()` and getting back `errno=ENOTTY`. That can happen if the shell process does not have a controlling terminal. The kernel doesn't set that up before running `init` on `/dev/console`.

You have already discovered the solution: use a real terminal device like `/dev/tty0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system error generated from the ‘bash’ program during its attempt to initialize job control.  The pid of the calling process, the process group id, and the session group id must all match and the shell must be the controlling terminal.

Here is the code from bash’s jobs.c file
[from the [gnu.org bash project repository](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c#n4481)]:

```c
  if (shell_pgrp != original_pgrp && shell_pgrp != terminal_pgrp)
    {
      if (give_terminal_to (shell_pgrp, 0) < 0)
        {
          t_errno = errno;
          setpgid (0, original_pgrp);
          shell_pgrp = original_pgrp;
          errno = t_errno;
          sys_error (_("cannot set terminal process group (%d)"), shell_pgrp);
          job_control = 0;
        }
    }

  if (job_control && ((t = tcgetpgrp (shell_tty)) == -1 || t != shell_pgrp))
    {
      if (t_errno != -1)
        errno = t_errno;
      sys_error (_("cannot set terminal process group (%d)"), t);
      job_control = 0;
    }
```

Since you ‘passed’ the first conditional, your session id matches your process group id.  However, your setup fails the second conditional.  You get a ‘-1’ response (error) when you run `tcgetpgrp`. 
The `t` variable is set to -1 and seen in the output.  This fails because in your environment, your shell is not configured as the controlling terminal.  As such, when you call the `tcgetpgrp` function, which calls the `ioctl()` system level function, it basically says you cannot call this ioctl on a shell that is not the controlling terminal.  That is, it is inappropriate.

Using the getty program before running the shell program takes care of correctly setting up the process id, process group id, session id, and shell to be the controlling terminal.  It then passes the checks in the bash program.