# error when launching pty from rust "cannot set terminal process group (14206): Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: linux, rust, pty

I'm trying to open a pty shell in my program, it seems to work somewhat but in the output there seems to be an error that shows up even though the program seems to work despite it
there also seems to be echoing happening but I don't know how to diable that

this program uses openpty function then writes the command `uname -r` to the master, then it waits for any incoming input and outputs it to the screen in a loop

### CODE:

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::os::fd::{FromRawFd};
use nix::pty::{openpty};
use nix::unistd::{ read, write };

fn launch_pty(shell: &str) -> i32 {
    let ends = openpty(None, None).expect("Failed to open pty");
    let master = ends.master;
    let slave = ends.slave;

    let mut command = Command::new(shell);
    command.stdin(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(slave) });
    command.stdout(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(slave) });
    command.stderr(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(slave) });

    match command.spawn()  {
        Ok(_) => {
            master
        },
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to create pty: {}", e);
        }
    }


}

fn main() {
    let pty = launch_pty("/bin/bash");
    write(pty, b"uname -r\n").unwrap();
    

    loop {
        let mut buffer = [0; 4096];
        match read(pty, &mut buffer) {
            Ok(bytes_read) => {
                println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buffer[0..bytes_read].to_vec()).unwrap());
            },
            Err(_) => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```

### Output:

```
uname -r
bash: cannot set terminal process group (14080): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
mahmoud@DESKTOP-MOT06CH:~/Documents/rust_terminal$ uname -r
5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

### Somewhat unrelated:

I also tried making the program execute `clear` instead of `uname -r` but that doesn't seem to clear the screen, I assumed it would output some ansi escape code that clears the screen but the `clear` command just produces no output

however this is undrelated so answering the original question is just fine I could always create a new question for this

Comment: `stty -echo` should disable echoing

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32090974/5397009

Comment: @Jmb hello, sorry for the late reply, I found a way to diable echoing by calling tcgetattr on the slave, flipping the ECHO bit in in local flags, then calling tcsetattr on the slave again, so this is no problem anymore, I also fixed the `clear` keyword not working, my only issue now is the error message that is not affecting the program at all, I would just prefer not having it there